# How did they create the prop of Han Solo in Carbonite?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

Curious if there is anything out there that describes how they made the life size figure of Han in Carbonite.

Was it a full body cast, if so how did they get the clothes, or was it an artistic sculpture?

Comment: I contacted the artist about this. If he is amenable, we could receive a WoG answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was a cast (as was Mark Hamil's hand getting cut off). I haven't found any interviews but [this tweet](https://twitter.com/twiggystar/status/464795810027536386) says it took 20 mins to make the face as shown

[image: Image: Making the cast on Harrison Ford's face]

Fun fact: only Harrison's face was cast. They [used a body double for the rest](http://starwarsinterviews1.blogspot.com/2010/05/alan-harris-interview-bossk-star-wars.html) (was the same actor who played Bossk the bounty hunter).

> **Q:** You were the body double for Han Solo in carbonite. How did this came to be?
>
> **A:** Irvin Kershner had the idea. We were in the props room where they put a shroud over me and two drinking straws through my nose so I could breath. They later cut my face out and put Harrison Ford’s in. Irvin Kershner and I looked at the finished product on the set and Harrison came over. He said he was thinking of turning one of these into a coffee table. I don’t know if he ever did.

Comment: That's not the coffee table of a carpenter...

Comment: IT BELONGS IN A MUSEUM!

Comment: Hamill didn't really cut off his hand? And here I was thinking he was a professional.